# Map one instance of many models to one property in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Say I have the following DB structure:

```
asset:                         metadata_text:
 id | type | source             asset_id | font_size | font_color | font_name
----|------|-----------        ----------|-----------|------------|-----------
 0  | vid  | http://...         2        | 24        | #FF8800    | Arial
 1  | img  | http://...                            ...
 2  | text | null
      ...

metadata_vid:                                 metadata_img:
 asset_id | width | height | length            asset_id | width | height 
----------|-------|--------|--------          ----------|-------|--------
 0        | 1920  | 1080   | 1303              1        | 400   | 400
                ...                                      ...
```

I have assets with certain `type`s, and each `type` has a metadata table associated with it. An asset only has one entry in one of the metadata tables. How would I map an asset's metadata to a single property in EF core? I would like my Asset entity to look like

```cs
public class Asset
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public object Metadata { get; set; }  // populate this with the entry from the relevant table
}
```

Is there any way to do this using EF Core? I understand that you can do type inheritance however this doesn't help my situation as it requires all metadata fields for all types to be in the same table as the assets. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: As far as I know, you can map database views in EF Core. So, you would have to create a view unifying all these metadata fields and them map it to an entity class.

Comment: "An asset only has one entry in one of the metadata tables."  Do you have database constraints to enforce this?  Otherwise inconsistent data is going to be a real problem.  Is the database design already set?  Seems to me this should all be in one table.

Comment: Thanks, I'm unifying all the fields into the asset table. This question was mainly born from my own curiosity, I'm sure this method will actually work fine :)

Comment: I was just reviewing this question and realized if you make the asset_id the primary key of the metadata tables, then the `1 -> 0..1` relationship would be enforced.  In any case, glad the conversation was useful.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately table per type (TPT) inheritance is not supported in EF Core yet and this sounds like a great use case for it:
[GitHub TPT issue #2266](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2266)

What would be the disadvantage of having a separate property for each?

There may then be a way to use AutoMapper to map all the properties to the properties of a single class within a model class. Or at least create your own mappings.

Comment: More than a use case for it..."table per type" methodology has already been used to model data on the relational side.  It's clearly a hierarchical structure in my opinion.

Comment: I'm leaning into just having a separate property for each - I wanted to avoid it bc the asset types and their necessary metadata isn't finalised yet so I wanted to encapsulate them. I was hoping to prevent someone in the future looking to add a new field to the VideoAsset metadata and having to change the whole table. But it seems that wouldn't be as bad as I thought anyway

Comment: If it is not too late to change the DB structure the meta data could be pivoted to one table so new fields would instead be new rows. E.g. with columns for meta type, name and value. No future table changes needed for additional data

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking to your model is pretty unorthodox.  First let me explain what one might normally do.

The problem appears to be a hierarchical class structure scenario that you are modeling in your relational database with a table-per-type methodology.

Normally you'd model the structure in memory like this:

```
public class Asset
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

public class VideoAsset : Asset
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
}

public class TextAsset : Asset
{
   public decimal fontSize { get; set; }
   public string fontColor { get; set; }
   public string fontName { get; set; }
}

public class ImageAsset : Asset
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}
```

Using an in-memory model like this requires your ORM supports table-per-type mapping.  EF Core does not support this although EF 6+ does.

As far as packing all of the metadata tables into one entity, if you really want to do that you could use a SQL view to create an "All Metadata" entity:

```
public class Asset
{
    public Asset()
    {
        Metadata = new HashSet<AssetMetadata>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AssetMetadata> Metadata { get; set; }
}

public class AssetMetadata 
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public decimal fontSize { get; set; }
    public string fontColor { get; set; }
    public string fontName { get; set; }
}
```

However, I'd really recommend you stick with a more conventional way of modeling, where each table is just associated with an entity, like this:

```
public class Asset
{
    public Asset()
    {
        VideoAsset = new HashSet<VideoAsset>();
        TextAsset = new HashSet<TextAsset>();
        ImageAsset = new HashSet<ImageAsset>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public ICollection<VideoAsset> VideoAsset { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TextAsset> TextAsset { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ImageAsset> ImageAsset { get; set; }
}


public class VideoAsset 
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
}

public class TextAsset
{
   public int AssetId { get; set; }
   public decimal fontSize { get; set; }
   public string fontColor { get; set; }
   public string fontName { get; set; }
}

public class ImageAsset
{
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}
```